Web Scrapping Logical issue help (python)
I'm working on a web scraping project to extract MCQs and answers from Indiabix.  I've already created CSV files with links to all the topics.

The problem I'm facing is that each topic page contains multiple sets of MCQs within <div class="exercise mb-3"> elements. I need to loop through each of these URLs and handle pagination to scrape all the MCQs.
For example, the first URL, problem on train  has four exercise URLs. I want to check each of these URLs, handle pagination if necessary, and scrape all MCQs. After finishing one exercise, I want the script to move on to the next exercise and repeat the process.
Here is my code snipped; Any help appreciated.
import csv
import logging
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Setup logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='scraper.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Initialize WebDriver
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  # Start browser maximized
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")  # Disable extensions
service = Service(r'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')  # Update path to your chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Define the folder where your CSV files are located
csv_folder = "E:\\Python\\MCQ\\MCQ"

# Iterate over each CSV file in the folder
for csv_file_name in os.listdir(csv_folder):
    if csv_file_name.endswith('.csv'):
        # Create a folder with the same name as the CSV file (without the .csv extension)
        base_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.splitext(csv_file_name)[0])
        os.makedirs(base_folder, exist_ok=True)

        # Open the CSV file and iterate over the rows
        csv_file_path = os.path.join(csv_folder, csv_file_name)
        with open(csv_file_path, mode='r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(reader)  # Skip the header row

            for row in reader:
                topic_name, base_url = row[0], row[1]

                # Create a new folder for each topic inside the base folder
                topic_folder = os.path.join(base_folder, topic_name)
                os.makedirs(topic_folder, exist_ok=True)

                # Path for the single CSV file for the topic
                quiz_file_path = os.path.join(topic_folder, f"{topic_name}.csv")
                topic_questions = []

                # Open the base URL
                driver.get(base_url)

                try:
                    # Wait for the page to load
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.exercise.mb-3'))
                    )

                    # Find all URLs within the class="exercise mb-3"
                    url_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.exercise.mb-3 a')
                    urls = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in url_elements if elem.get_attribute('href')]

                    for url in urls:
                        logging.info(f"Processing URL: {url}")

                        # Directly open the URL without appending page numbers
                        driver.get(url)

                        try:
                            # Wait for the page to load
                            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bix-td-qtxt.table-responsive.w-100'))
                            )

                            # Scrape data from the page
                            questions = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bix-td-qtxt.table-responsive.w-100')
                            if not questions:  # If no questions are found, log and skip
                                logging.info(f"No questions found at URL {url}.")
                                continue

                            while True:
                                for question in questions:
                                    try:
                                        question_text = question.text
                                        options = question.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bix-tbl-options .bix-opt-row')
                                        option_dict = {'A': '', 'B': '', 'C': '', 'D': '', 'E': ''}  # Include option E
                                        for option in options:
                                            option_id = option.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bix-td-option span').get_attribute('class')
                                            option_text = option.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bix-td-option-val .flex-wrap').text
                                            if 'mdi-alpha-a-circle-outline' in option_id:
                                                option_dict['A'] = option_text
                                            elif 'mdi-alpha-b-circle-outline' in option_id:
                                                option_dict['B'] = option_text
                                            elif 'mdi-alpha-c-circle-outline' in option_id:
                                                option_dict['C'] = option_text
                                            elif 'mdi-alpha-d-circle-outline' in option_id:
                                                option_dict['D'] = option_text
                                            elif 'mdi-alpha-e-circle-outline' in option_id:  # Check for option E
                                                option_dict['E'] = option_text

                                        # Get the answer
                                        answer_element = question.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id^=hdnAnswer_]')
                                        answer = answer_element.get_attribute('value')

                                        # Map the answer to letter format
                                        answer_letter = {'A': 'A', 'B': 'B', 'C': 'C', 'D': 'D', 'E': 'E'}.get(answer, '')

                                        # Collect question data
                                        topic_questions.append([
                                            question_text,
                                            option_dict['A'],
                                            option_dict['B'],
                                            option_dict['C'],
                                            option_dict['D'],
                                            option_dict['E'],  # Include option E
                                            answer_letter
                                        ])
                                        logging.info(f"Scraped question: {question_text}")

                                    except Exception as e:
                                        logging.error(f"Error scraping question: {e}")

                                # Check for pagination
                                pagination_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.pagination.justify-content-center.flex-wrap')
                                if pagination_elements:
                                    # Handle pagination
                                    next_page_link = pagination_elements[0].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.page-item.active + li a')
                                    next_page_url = next_page_link.get_attribute('href')
                                    driver.get(next_page_url)
                                    # Wait for the next page to load
                                    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bix-td-qtxt.table-responsive.w-100'))
                                    )
                                    questions = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bix-td-qtxt.table-responsive.w-100')
                                else:
                                    break  # Exit the loop if there's no pagination

                        except Exception as e:
                            logging.error(f"Error processing page at URL {url}: {e}")

                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"Error processing base URL {base_url}: {e}")

                # Save questions to a single CSV file for the topic
                if topic_questions:
                    with open(quiz_file_path, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as quiz_file:
                        writer = csv.writer(quiz_file)
                        writer.writerow(['Question', 'Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C', 'Option D', 'Option E', 'Answer'])  # Include Option E
                        writer.writerows(topic_questions)
                        logging.info(f"Saved questions to {quiz_file_path}")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

I want to Scrape exercise wise all page's mcq and export csv for each topic. Suppose this url open https://www.indiabix.com/aptitude/problems-on-trains/ it scrapes all 7 page question answer and then check next exercise "Problems on Trains - Data Sufficiency 1" and so on.
